# How do I set custom bash prompt / env variables / aliases in a way that the user can restore their previous settings at any point?

Tags: bash, terminal, environment-variables, command-prompt, environment

So I have written a tool that generates and offline replica of another system. It allows you to run commands typically run online, offline by specify a series of .mgmt and .sock files in the command.

However, I want users to be able to enter these commands as if they were on the live system. Therefore, I had it generate a script that can be sourced to set the environment variables and aliases necessary to allow the user to enter commands easily.

There are a few issues this created that I want to work around, and I am curious is there is a standard best practice when doing this.

1. I want the bash prompt to change (or atleast be appended to) when the user sources the new variables so it is clear they are running commands on the offline replica. I can do this by setting $PS1. However, I also want a 'deactivate' script to restore the previous user environment. How do I undo this change to the previous one?
2. When they source my script, env variables change that may have been previously set. I have the script store any previous variables as OLD_<env_variable_name> and create a second deactivate script that restores them as well as removes any aliases (and eventually resets the bash prompt). Is this the best way to do this, or is there a much simpler method I may be missing?

Comment: You'll want to see how other tools do it, like `pyenv`

Comment: Right, I see what they are doing. Wasn't too far off from what I had done. Great, thank you!